# Imagemagick bash script not working

Tags: bash, imagemagick

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/posix/path/to/folder"
cd "$dir"

color1 = "#816c51"
color2 = "#5a4a3b"
color3 = "#1c110f"

for file in *.tiff
do
    base=${file%*.tif}
    convert -unsharp 5 "$base" "$base.ppm"
    convert -opaque white -fill white -fuzz 10% "$base.ppm" "${base}_step1.tif"
    convert -fuzz 5% -fill "$color1" -opaque "$color1" "${base}_step1.tif" "${base}_step2.tif"
    convert -fuzz 1.5% -fill "$color1" -opaque "$color2" "${base}_step2.tif" "${base}_step3.tif"
    convert -fuzz 12% -fill "black" -opaque "$color3" "${base}_step3.tif" "${base}_step4.tif"
    convert "${base}_step4.tif" "${base}_final.tif"
done
```

I get a couple of error:

`convert: unable to open image ...`
`convert: missing an image filename`
`test.sh: line 6: color1: command not found`

I'd really appreciate some help! Thanks!

Comment: `color1: command not found`--remove the spaces around `=`.

Comment: And, in addition to ruakh's post, in `convert -unsharp 5 "$base" "$base.ppm"`, you probably want `"$file"` not `"$base"` as the first file arg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit unclear on what this is trying to do (I don't have much experience with ImageMagick), but from a Bash standpoint, I can tell you that this bit:

```
for file in *.tiff
do
    base=${file%*.tif}
```

does not make sense: it tries to strip off a final `.tif` (one F) from a file-name that ends in `.tiff` (two F's). You presumably meant either this:

```
for file in *.tiff
do
    base="${file%.tiff}"
```

(which strips off the final `.tiff`) or this:

```
for file in *.tif
do
    base="${file%.tif}"
```

(which finds files ending in `.tif`); or, perhaps, this:

```
for file in *.tiff *.tif
do
    base="${file%.tiff}"
    base="${base%.tif}"
```

(which handles both cases).

You also probably want to explicitly check for the case that `"$base"` is `'*'` (which will happen, for example, if you try to use `*.tif` in a directory that doesn't contain any files matching that name).

Comment: That worked great, you guys are awesome! just one last thing: how do I delete the generated step files once the final image is produced? Thanks heaps!

Comment: @Nimbuz: There are a few ways. One is, after the entire loop is over (that is, after the `done` statement), to write `rm *_step?.tif`. That will remove any file whose name ends in `_step1.tif` or `_stepX.tif` or `_step_.tif` or the like.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure entirely if I can fully help because the full extent of the problem isn't relevant, but I see you have "*.tiff" (with two f) and then later everything else is "*.tif" (with one f). So maybe that is why it can't find the filenames.

Also get rid of the spaces in color1 = "blah" (e.g. color1="blah") and that line will work.